# App is Crashing when clicking UINavigation back button ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, crash, calayer

When i tried to click one button it moved to next UIViewcontroller and from there i click back button and it came back to the previous UIViewcontroller  ,suddently it crashed.
Following are the crash report

```
2013-08-19 12:02:19.849 MyApp[851:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <CALayerArray: 0x1f1f1120> was mutated while being enumerated.' *** First throw call stack: (0x34a1d2a3 0x3c67797f 0x34a1cd85 0x36827ca3 0x36827d33 0x36827d33 0x36827d33 0x36827d33 0x36827b9b 0x36a0b585 0x368538af 0x368a3f19 0x3683aab3 0x368af8ef 0x365e4c01 0x3ca8e4b7 0x3ca8fdcb 0x349f0f3b 0x34963ebd 0x34963d49 0x384e02eb 0x36879301 0xdc439 0xdc3c0) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: is that backButton action is custom or default? if custom then post your backButton Click event code.

Comment: Please share same code on button action.

Comment: the SO search results for `CALayerArray was mutated while being enumerated` indicate that you might manipulate your UI from a thread that is not the mainThread.

Comment: @NitinGohel its a default one

Comment: @SuryakantSharma ok  i'll share

Comment: Do you have a collection view or table view in your first viewcontroller ?

Comment: @AdarshVC Yes,I'm Using PSTCollectionView

Comment: @MatthiasBauch  :iam trying to disaply some images fro server to a image view which is lying inside a uiscrollview.If the images are not theer then its crashing

Comment: Make sure that the datasource and delegate of collection view is not dead(null) when you came back from secondviewcontroller.

Comment: you mean i have to declare satasource and delegates are in viewdidappear() ?

Comment: @AdarshVC  but all delegate and datat source are setting in story board file(design) right?

Comment: Just try to NSLog to make sure delegate and datasource are not null.

Comment: @AdarshVC with NSLOG ??? how?

Comment: Possibly your datasource will be some array or fetched result controller rite ?

Comment: @AdarshVC  its  array,now iam checking that array is empty or not

Comment: @AdarshVC  its not empty i just checked now

Comment: Does it got updated ?

Comment: yup,each time am taking value from plist